# capybara and click_on method + simple_form [javascript error]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, simple-form

I'm using minitest, capybara and poltergeist and this is the simple_form to test:

```
<%= simple_form_for :search,  url: ads_path , wrapper: :inline_form, html: {class: 'form-inline'}, :method => :get do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= f.input :type_id, collection: @types, label_html: {class: 'form_home'}, selected: 'house'%>
  <%= f.input :city, label: 'Where?', placeholder: 'What is the city ?'%>
  <br>
  <br>
  <%= f.submit "Search", :class => "btn btn-primary btn-xl page-scroll" %>
<% end %>
```

The problem relies when I add the **click_on 'Search'**

```
 test "search correctly" do
    visit "/"
    select "house", :from => "search_type_id"
    fill_in 'search_city' , with: ""
    click_on 'Search'
  end
```

The javascrip error on the terminal:

> Capybara::Poltergeist::JavascriptError:
>   Capybara::Poltergeist::JavascriptError: One or more errors were raised
>   in the Javascript code on the page. If you don't care about these
>   errors, you can ignore them by setting js_errors: false in your
>   Poltergeist configuration (see documentation for details).
>
> ```
>     Error: Bounds are not valid.
>     Error: Bounds are not valid.
>         at http://127.0.0.1:43411/assets/application-1442915127e4fa1072f69aa9aa4d07ce85cdc5115df9b3a40da528ee05ebfe94.js:43537
>         at http://127.0.0.1:43411/ads?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search%5Btype_id%5D=1&search%5Bcity%5D=&commit=Search:135
>         test/integration/home_test.rb:16:in `block in <class:HomeTest>'
> ```

Is there other alternative ?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options, fix your JS or disable JS error reporting as mentioned in the error message.

To fix your JS either start by looking at the combined JS line 43537 to see why it's logging "Bounds are not valid" or do the same behavior in dev mode to figure out which individual JS file is producing the error and start debugging from there.

If on the other hand you don't care about fixing the cause of the error (you should care about it though) then you can configure your driver to not report JS errors with

```
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, js_errors: false)
end
```

as mentioned in the Poltergeist readme - https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist#customization

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sorry for the delay. I tried what you sad and couldn't resolve this issue but I decided to go to Rspec instead for other reasons! Now I'm going well ;)